# CORS Issue with AWS Lambda and Ajax

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have been working on this serverless configuration that calls a Lambda function through ajax. The I enable CORs through the API Gateway, and I have made sure of the domain I specified. This domain works when calling other lambda functions within the same API.

Now for the weird stuff.

I send a post request (I am trying to upload a file through ajax, lambda, and S3), to my API. If I configure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin so that it points to the domain WITHOUT the http in front of it. Ex: example.com. When I try to call this i get:

```
Failed to load https://m562ogkc1l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/upload: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Ok fine, this is assumed, since that's not the proper domain. So when I add in the http (http://example.com) for the CORs of the API I get:

```
Failed to load https://m562ogkc1l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/upload: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

What this seems like to me is that there is an issue elsewhere, except I don't know where the issue lies.

I have made sure the data I pass for parameters of the ajax call are strignified (JSON.stringify()), and I am NOT running an AWS Lambda Proxy which means I shouldn't be configuring responses on the lambda side of things.

This all really confuses me and I wish AWS had better documentation and examples since they really want to push these serverless services.

Further code is here:

Ajax:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    //console.log(document.getElementById('fileUpload').value.substring(12));//C:\fakepath\ in front of filename (size = 12)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://m562ogkc1l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/upload',
      data: JSON.stringify({"id": id,"name": document.getElementById('fileUpload').value.substring(12),"body": document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0]}),
      contentType: "application/json", 
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //location.reload();
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Lambda:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
   let encodedImage = JSON.parse(event.body);
   let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
   var filePath = event.id + '/' + event.name
   var params = {
      "Body": decodedImage,
      "Bucket": "repository.example.com",
      "Key": filePath  
  };
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            let response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://example.com" 
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(err),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            };
            resolve(response);
        } else {
            let response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://example.com" 
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(data),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            };
            resolve(response);
          }
      });
   });
};
```

(Yes I threw in some response configuration for the function, I just wanted to see if it would work)

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 400.*  That's a `Bad Request`.  Does `document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0]` actually give you a base64 string?

Comment: The CORS behavior makes sense, incidentally.  In the first case, you're failing pre-flight.  In the second, pre-flight succeeds but the actual request has some kind of problem, so API Gateway rejects it out-of-hand, never firing the Lambda function.  Using `curl` to debug this would be much easier than using the browser.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the document.get function returns a file JSON object with information regarding the file as well as the body. Does it need to be a base64?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be base64, because your (1) code is expecting that: `let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');` and (2) JSON can't correctly serialize binary data without using base64 or some kind of text-compatible encoding.